# How to access after flag.Args()

Tags: go

My app is a huge application for download from netease.It meets problem at first.

```golang
func main() {
    if len(flag.Args()) == 0 {
        logger.Error.Fatal("Missing music address:(")
    }
}
```

After compiling,I get ncm-dl.exe and when I run `./ncm-dl.exe xxxxx`.I get

```golang
[Error] 2021/08/31 22:06:59 Missing music address:(
```

I want to know what's up when I run.

Here is my logger package.

```golang
package logger

import (
    "os"
    "log"
)

var (
    Error   = log.New(os.Stderr, "[Error] ", log.LstdFlags)
)
```

Comment: Call flags.Parse.

Comment: Did you call flags.Parse?

Comment: All right, all right.I know what I did wrong.I need flags.Parse()

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `flag.Parse` before doing anything:

```
package main
import "flag"

func main() {
   flag.Parse()
   if flag.NArg() == 0 {
      println("fail")
      return
   }
   println("pass")
}
```

https://godocs.io/flag#Parse